# Ending nodes/topics from python script

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! To preface, I working with a turtlebot3 running ROS on Ubuntu, and working with the package frontier-exploration. I am designing a Python script that will send the turtlebot to its point of origin when the battery is low, and stop when it reaches that point. It operates by specifying a very small perimeter around the bot's point of origin. Now the problem: I want the bot to completely stop moving when it reaches its goal, but I cannot seem to publish a Twist to cmd_vel that will stop the bot. Is there a way that I can shutdown frontier-exploration from my Python script? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295503/ending-nodes/topics-from-python-script/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-27**:
Can you please update your question with what you've attempted so far (i.e., your code)?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-06-27**:
You should post a new question about your inability to stop the robot using commands. Shutting down the node is a heavy-handed way to stop frontier-exploration and there should be a better way. (If there isn't, your question might trigger someone to produce one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can manage nodes from a Python program using the [roslaunch API](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage). Keep in mind that this API is listed as "very unstable", although it has been in that state since forever and to be honest I don't think it will change that much from now on.

The [`rosmon` tool](http://wiki.ros.org/rosmon) might also interest you. It replaces `roslaunch`, and as well as several other useful features, it provides a ROS service that you can use to start and stop nodes.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1